# Customer name shouldn't display after rebooting the system

Tags: magento2, cache, magento2.2.2, header, block-cache

Steps to reproduce.

- login as a user
- close the tab without logged out
- restart the system
- open browser and open magento local
- see the welcome message

ACTUAL RESULTS
 - Welcome!User name!
 - Sign in
 - Create an account

Expected Results
 **- Welcome!
 - Sign In
 - Create an account**

Comment: I think you should move this to git Not Here.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/new

Comment: In expected result you mentioned that it shows sign In Because you logged out adn then restarted system and again you open magento you need to login then only it will show user name in welcome message.

Comment: No I didnt logged out i just closed the tab

Comment: then are you able to access "my account " ?

Comment: No i'm not.I can if i didnt closed the tab and also not logged out

Comment: it means you are not logged in right ?

Comment: yeahh.after closing the tab i should logged out automatically right??